# Xcode compiling keeps taking more space from HD?

Tags: xcode, macos, project, hard-drive

I have a project where I have some regular files and some 3rd party libraries. I also have 2 static libraries. The problem is, whenever I build my project, my Laptop's HD space keeps decreasing.

Is my build being held somewhere? How come it continuously keeps taking more and more space from my HD?

So far I have lost about 20GB from this issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the 20GB still lost after a complete reboot? Did you try to clean the project (in the the "product" menu).

Comment: Haven't checked your first question. But if I do clean, then rebuild thats when I lose even more space in my HD during the build.

Comment: Did you try to clean the build itself? You can find them through this path: `/Users/{user}/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/5.1/Applications/`, every simulator has its own folder. You should try to delete all the folders that has this kind of signature: `1890A6A8-3EBB-443A-B220-CB8BE265999B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record so that this can be archived as answered:

Did you try to clean the build itself? You can find them through this path: `/Users/{user}/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/5.1/Applications/`, every simulator has its own folder. You should try to delete all the folders that has this kind of signature: `1890A6A8-3EBB-443A-B220-CB8BE265999B`.

Comment: Yes that was the fix! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check are the *PrecompiledHeaders* folders with hashed names in *DerivedData/Build/Intermediates* and *DerivedData/.../Index* (at least for xcode 7). They simply accumulate with each build and can be tens of MB each.

A script to check their sizes is

```
find <your-dev-folder> -type d -path '*/DerivedData/*/PrecompiledHeaders' -exec du -s -m '{}' \; | sort -n
```

to remove them all do

```
find <your-dev-folder> -type d -path '*/DerivedData/*/PrecompiledHeaders' -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```